# gulp: Could not find an option named "sourcemap"

Tags: css, npm, sass, gulp

it's the fifth day when I'm fighting this and I'm almost ready to give up (but I can't). I picked up a project from someone else and I'm trying to make gulp work.

I ended up with "could not find an option named "sourcemap".

```
Starting 'watch'...
[11:48:54] Finished 'watch' after 2.75 s
[11:49:32] Starting 'styles'...
[11:49:33] Could not find an option named "sourcemap".
Usage: dart-sass <input>
```

in `gulpfile.js` I've got this:

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {
    return sass(['_/sass/main.scss', '_/sass/editor.scss', '_/sass/career-form.scss'], {
    sourcemap: true, style: "compact"
    })
})
```

even when I delete the `sourcemap: true` part, the error is still there. Gulp works with `js` files, but not with CSS. not sure if that matter.

I use `gulp-ruby-sass` and I tried everything there were related to the issue, but no luck. (The guy that worked before on that is not helpful - "*I don't know, go Google the error*").

I already tried to rebuild node_modules, five times, maybe more, checked different versions of `gulp-ruby-sass` and `gulp-sourcemaps`. Looked for another usage of `sourcemap` but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

From [the gulp-ruby-sass sourcemap option documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-sass#sourcemap) it looks like if you use the sourcemap option than you **must** also use [gulp-sourcemaps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps).

> sourcemap
>                 Type: boolean
>   Default: false
>
> Initialize and pass Sass sourcemaps to gulp-sourcemaps.

So their code:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('sass', () =>
    sass('source/file.scss', {sourcemap: true})
        .on('error', sass.logError)
        // for inline sourcemaps 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        // for file sourcemaps 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps', {
            includeContent: false,
            sourceRoot: 'source'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('result'))
);
```

So try them together.  [Why you still get an error message if you remove the sourcemap option is strange.]

Comment: the `sourcemaps` is there.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but still hope it could help.

If you use gulp-ruby-sass, you will have to install ruby.

However, gulp-ruby-sass has been deprecated, so it's better to switch to gulp-sass to compile Sass files.